# ag Silver Searcher: List ignored/searched files

Tags: ag

ag provides multiple mechanisms for ignoring files (hidden files, VCS ignored files, .agignore ...). These are quite helpful, but sometimes this makes me wonder which files in my file tree are actually ignored / searched. Is there a quick way to check this?

I tried `ag '^'` to get a list of searched files, but 0 bytes files were not included in it.

Comment: What does this have to do with the UNIX tool `grep`? Read [ask] then [edit] your question to provide the missing [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no search query is provided, [the `-l` option](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/doc/ag.1.md) (that's a lower-case "L") lists the files that would be searched by `ag`:

> -l --files-with-matches: Only print the names of files containing matches, not the matching lines. An empty query will print all files that would be searched.